# Probability of the score of two rolls

Tags: probability

I have a probability problem and this is the request:

What is the probability that the score of the first roll is higher than the score of a second roll. The rolls are equilibrated and independent. (I think one per time)

I have solved this problem with this method: $P(X>Y)=P(X-Y>0)= \frac{15}{36}$ with the help of a grid with all the possible $X-Y$ scores.

Is this a good way of resolution? If not, help me with a good method.

Thank you

Comment: Yes, for a problem with a 'low' amount of possible outcomes, gridding them out should work. Your answer is correct. Independence means the outcome of the second roll does not depend on the first roll (and vice versa), which should be the case if you are rolling dice.

Comment: Nothing wrong with this method.  If you want another (that scales up better with the number of cases):  The probability of a tie is $\frac 16$.  If we aren't in a tie then $P(X>Y)=P(Y>X)$ by symmetry.  Thus $P(X>Y)=\frac 12\times \left( 1-\frac 16\right)=\frac 5{12}$, just as you got.  Note that you could use this method to easily handle the case of an $N$ sided die.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with your solution; enumeration is a terrific technique and sometimes it's all there is.  If you want a method that can handle a large number of cases better:

The probability of a tie is $\frac 16$.  If we aren't in a tie then $P(X>Y)=P(Y>X)$ by symmetry.  Thus $$P(X>Y)=\frac 12\times \left( 1-\frac 16\right)=\frac 5{12}$$ just as you got.  Note that you could use this method to easily handle the case of an $N$ sided die.

Comment: thanks for your help, can you give me an explaination about $1/2$ in your formula? Because we have two rolls?

Comment: No.  It's because you have two cases.  $X>Y$ and $Y>X$.  As I say, these must be equally probable.  They don't add to $1$ because it is possible that there is a tie.  Note that for a very large $N$ the probability of a tie is negligible so you should expect $P(X>Y)\to \frac 12$.  You could confirm that this is true analytically.

Comment: everything it's ok, thanks. I have voted your answer